# Display/format UTC time in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have converted a bunch of dates in my controller to UTC in order to display the in the view.

Im running into a weird problem trying to format them though..

```
<label>{{ '2016-07-22T10:45:00.000Z' | date : "shortTime"}}</label>
```

I would expect that code to display something like:

```
//10:45
```

Instead it displays

```
//3:45 AM
```

3:45 is the local time on my computer. 
Any idea what causes this or how I can display `10:45`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

All you need to do is adding : 'UTC' after the format string.

```
<label>{{ '2016-07-22T10:45:00.000Z' | date:' HH:mm:ss ' : 'UTC' }}</label>
```

Comment: Worked! :) Will accept this answer asap. Thank you!